# wrong value converting integer data to date on vb.net

Tags: vb.net, datetime

I have a series of data that I get from an access control device, the data is the following:

Cardno, Pin, Verified, DoorID, EventType, InOutState, Time_second

3189959,13978762,4,2,0,0,676132501

Time_second(676132501) should be "2021-01-14 14:58:54.000"

this is my code

```
Dim sDate As Integer = 676132501

Dim dtDateTime As System.DateTime = New DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, System.DateTimeKind.Utc)
dtDateTime = dtDateTime.AddSeconds(sDate).ToLocalTime()
```

the value returned is : #6/5/1991 10:35:01 AM#, please help

Comment: The date converted on https://www.epochconverter.com is: Wednesday, June 5, 1991 2:35:01 PM - so I believe VB.NET is doing the calculation correctly (the hour is different based on my timezone)

Comment: You should read specification of the data format you have and see how that conversion should be done. One option is to simply change base time till you get value you like... but there is no way for us to know if that is correct for your file format / device output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A quick google search of those field names you gave in the question landed on a technical spec doc of something called "PullSDK", which appears to be what you're using.  I won't link to it here because I could not find an *official* source.

The doc gives a formula for decoding these timestamps.  Translated to VB.Net it is as follows:

```vb
Function DecodeDateTime(ByVal t As Integer) As DateTime
    
    Dim year, month, day, hour, minute, second As Integer
    
    second = t Mod 60
    t /= 60
    minute = t Mod 60
    t /= 60
    hour = t Mod 24
    t /= 24
    day = t Mod 31 + 1
    t /= 31
    month = t Mod 12 + 1
    t /= 12
    year = t + 2000
    
    Return New DateTime(year, month, day, hour, minute, second)
    
End Function
```

The value you gave, `676132501` is decoded as `2021-01-15 15:35:01` - which is slightly different than your stated expectation.  You might want to carefully check the source of that data to verify your assumptions.

As an aside - in evaluating that formula, no amount of adding seconds to some base value would suffice.  This is because they've encoded the day into a space that always has 31 values within a month - even for months with less than 31 days.  That makes this encoding inefficient, as there will be some values that represent dates that don't actually exist.

Comment: Thanks.  If this answered your question, please accept it.  See https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers